# Scrollbar - the block increment seems variable not fixed

Tags: java, javafx

In the example below the block increment of the scrollbar is set to 100. However it appears that the actual value will be a value between 1 - 100 depending on where you click on the track bar.

When running the example try clicking roughly in the middle of the track several times to scroll down. When I do this I get output like:

```
ScrollBar Max: 400.0
LayoutY: -100.0
LayoutY: -200.0
LayoutY: -300.0
LayoutY: -375.0 // this varies depending on the click location
```

I am expecting the scroll units to change by 100 no matter where I click on the track. (ie, only a single label should be visible at a time).

Is this a common scrolling feature? If so, is there a way to turn it off?

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollBarSSCCE extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        int labelWidth = 300;
        int labelHeight = 100;

        String[] styles =
        {
            "-fx-background-color: #336699;",
            "-fx-background-color: #996633;",
            "-fx-background-color: #ff0000;",
            "-fx-background-color: #00ff00;",
            "-fx-background-color: #0000ff;"
        };

        VBox vb = new VBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < styles.length; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.setPrefWidth( labelWidth );
            label.setPrefHeight( labelHeight );
            label.setStyle( styles[i] );
            vb.getChildren().add( label );
        }

        ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar();
        sc.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        sc.setLayoutX(labelWidth);
        sc.setMin(0);
        sc.setMax( (styles.length - 1) * labelHeight);
        System.out.println("ScrollBar Max: " + sc.getMax());
        sc.setPrefHeight( labelHeight );
        sc.setUnitIncrement( labelHeight / 2 );
        sc.setBlockIncrement( labelHeight );

        sc.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) ->
            {
                double y = -new_val.doubleValue();
                System.out.println("LayoutY: " + y);
                vb.setLayoutY( y );
            });

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll(vb, sc);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, labelWidth+20, labelHeight);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ScrollBar SSCCE");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScrollBar.adjustValue(position)` method is responsible for this behaviour.

It basically has three steps:

1. determine a "position value" by using the relative location of the mouse pressed
2. determine the "new value" by using the block increment value (this is the value I want)
3. Determine whether to use the "position value" or the "new value".

Since I always want the "new value" I just removed step 3 from the `adjustValue(...)` method.

Here is the code for the custom `ScrollBar`:

```
ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar()
{
    @Override
    public void adjustValue(double position)
    {
        // figure out the "value" associated with the specified position

        double posValue = ((getMax() - getMin()) * Utils.clamp(0, position, 1)) + getMin();

        double newValue;

        if (Double.compare(posValue, getValue()) != 0)
        {
            if (posValue > getValue())
            {
                newValue = getValue() + getBlockIncrement();
            }
            else
            {
                newValue = getValue() - getBlockIncrement();
            }

            setValue( Utils.clamp(getMin(), newValue, getMax()) );
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*i cant give a good explanation*

`System.out.println("block increment: " +sc.getBlockIncrement());` is always the same, and when i tested it, it happens on both sides going down or going up, i think it has to do with the `ScrollBar.adjustValue(position);` so if i am to provide some sort of solution i will say adjust the `Value` when you most need it.

```
//in your value listener you can add these codes
if(new_val.doubleValue() > old_val.doubleValue()){ //going down
     if(sc.getMax()-sc.getBlockIncrement() < Math.abs(y)){
         sc.adjustValue(1);
      }
}else{//going up
    if(old_val.doubleValue() == sc.getBlockIncrement()){
        sc.adjustValue(0);
    }
}
```

i think with this you might want to set `sc.setUnitIncrement(labelHeight/2);` the same as `sc.setBlockIncrement(labelHeight);` as that code might ruing the flow of `UnitIncrement`

hope it hepls :)

Comment: Yes, the `adjustValue(...)` method is the key. I was just looking at it when I noticed your posting (+1). As you suggest, this approach would force the block/unit increments to be the same value, which I don't want.